# Websocket not getting socket information

Tags: php, websocket

i've just recently been trying to get a Web socket working for my new client chat.

I'm running XAMPP on localhost and have made sure my socket locations are correct.

The socket connects to the chat due to chat messaged or Connected! but when I refresh the page, the messages are lost and the command prompt shows this error:

[Image of command prompt error](https://gyazo.com/fa2367b9e4109c8948257c9b02311f4f)

Here is my server.php code :

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; //host
$port = '900'; //port
$null = NULL; //null var

//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

//bind socket to specified host
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);

//listen to port
socket_listen($socket);

//create & add listning socket to the list
$clients = array($socket);

//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (true) {
    //manage multipal connections
    $changed = $clients;
    //returns the socket resources in $changed array
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

    //check for new socket
    if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
        $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accpet new socket
        $clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array

        $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024); //read data sent by the socket
        perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

        socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip); //get ip address of connected socket
        $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' connected'))); //prepare json data
        send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection

        //make room for new socket
        $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
        unset($changed[$found_socket]);
    }

    //loop through all connected sockets
    foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) { 

        //check for any incomming data
        while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)
        {
            $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
            $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 
            $user_name = $tst_msg->name; //sender name
            $user_message = $tst_msg->message; //message text
            $user_color = $tst_msg->color; //color

            //prepare data to be sent to client
            $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'usermsg', 'name'=>$user_name, 'message'=>$user_message, 'color'=>$user_color)));
            send_message($response_text); //send data
            break 2; //exist this loop
        }

        $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
            // remove client for $clients array
            $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
            socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
            unset($clients[$found_socket]);

            //notify all users about disconnected connection
            $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' disconnected')));
            send_message($response);
        }
    }
}
// close the listening socket
socket_close($socket);

function send_message($msg)
{
    global $clients;
    foreach($clients as $changed_socket)
    {
        @socket_write($changed_socket,$msg,strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}


//Unmask incoming framed message
function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Encode message for transfer to client.
function mask($text)
{
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}

//handshake new client.
function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port)
{
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
        {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
}
```

It gets to the lines 52, 53, and 54 when the errors hit.
It can't read the current users details.

My script for my main chat page is :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //create a new WebSocket object.
            var wsUri = "ws://localhost:900/New%20Login%20System/HazzJay/chat/server.php";
            websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 

            websocket.onopen = function(ev) { // connection is open 
                $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connected!</div>"); //notify user
            }

            $('#send-btn').click(function(){ //use clicks message send button   
                var mymessage = $('#message').val(); //get message text
                var myname = $('#name').val(); //get user name

                if(myname == ""){ //empty name?
                    alert("Enter your Name please!");
                    return;
                }
                if(mymessage == ""){ //emtpy message?
                    alert("Enter Some message Please!");
                    return;
                }
                document.getElementById("name").style.visibility = "hidden";

                var objDiv = document.getElementById("message_box");
                objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
                //prepare json data
                var msg = {
                message: mymessage,
                name: myname,
                color : '<?php echo $colours[$user_colour]; ?>'
                };
                //convert and send data to server
                websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
            });

            //#### Message received from server?
            websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
                var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data); //PHP sends Json data
                var type = msg.type; //message type
                var umsg = msg.message; //message text
                var uname = msg.name; //user name
                var ucolor = msg.color; //color

                if(type == 'usermsg') 
                {
                    $('#message_box').append("<div><span class=\"user_name\" style=\"color:#"+ucolor+"\">"+uname+"</span> : <span class=\"user_message\">"+umsg+"</span></div>");
                }
                if(type == 'system')
                {
                    $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">"+umsg+"</div>");
                }

                $('#message').val(''); //reset text

                var objDiv = document.getElementById("message_box");
                objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
            };

            websocket.onerror   = function(ev){$('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_error\">Error Occurred - "+ev.data+"</div>");}; 
            websocket.onclose   = function(ev){$('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connection Closed</div>");}; 
        });
</script>
```

I want it to load the previous messages in the chat even if a page is refreshed.

Comment: If you want to load all previous messages on page refresh you will need to store the messages in a database or some other storage. Then when a user first connects you will need to retrieve them and send them to the user.

Comment: Also you can modify your ws connection to just `"ws://localhost:900` you don't need this: `"ws://localhost:900/New%20Login%20System/HazzJay/chat/server.php"`

Comment: Also I would highly recommend looking into something like Ratchet (http://socketo.me/) as it has a lot of this stuff already done for you in a much cleaner way.